# javascripting which website accept to post javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, adsense

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-8338866757008397" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Where I can post this as required by Ad Sense

Comment: Put it in-between the <head> tags in your html. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/6437335 for why

Comment: After you've generated the AdSense code, you need to paste it between the <head> and </head> tags of your site.  as mentioned in adsense document

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-8338866757008397" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <title>Your Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is the body of your page.
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**As they mentioned in the document of** **AdSense**, After you've generated the AdSense code, you need to paste it between the  and  tags of your site.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9274516?hl=en

```
<html>
<head>
 <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890123456" async 
 src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">. 
 </script>
This is the head of your page.
<title>Example HTML page</title>
</head>
<body>
This is the body of your page.
</body>
</html>
```